# Scope variables are not binded in directive for jQuery plugin

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to bind 2 values from an input field to a scope variable. First is an input's value (color, written as text), and the second one is an attribute value (opacity value). I want them to change, and, as well, I want so their value be outputted.

```
myApp.directive( 'watchOpacity', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function( scope, element, attributes ) {
            scope.$watch( attributes.opacity, function(value) {
                console.log( 'opacity changed to', value );     
            });
        }   
    };
})
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/FcUjZNnqWhIUcF7PY9Yn?p=preview)

The problem is that neither the input's value, nor the attribute's value is displayed/binded.

Comment: One thing that is sure when I see your script.js file is that you have given string values to your color and opacity attributes. Thus it can never bind them to any value.

Comment: Why it cannot bind them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `change` callback jQuery MiniColors provides. It will have hex and opacity passed in as arguments, which you can use to set your `scope.data` properties.

You need to wrap the setting of those properties in a `scope.$apply` callback to ensure a digest cycle is run afterwards, so that your view is updated:

```
.directive( 'watchOpacity', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          watchOpacity: '='
        },
        link: function( scope, element, attributes, ngModel ) {
            $timeout(function(){
                element.attr('data-opacity', scope.watchOpacity);
                $(element).minicolors({
                  opacity: true,
                  defaultValue: ngModel.$modelValue || '',
                  change: function(hex, opacity) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(hex);
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.watchOpacity = opacity;
                    })
                  }
                });
            });
        }   
    }
})
```

Using this directive, your view would look like this (`ng-init` is optional depending upon whether or not you require default values or if you've placed them in the controller):

```
<input type="text" watch-opacity="data2.opacity" ng-model="data2.color"
ng-init="data2.color = '#0000FF'; data2.opacity = 0.5;" />
```

[Working fork of your demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCaHl6hsxVRq6DZT2W1P?p=preview)

Comment: any way to chenge it so that the color value would be linked to value defined in ng-model attribute (as it should be and work, by default, but somehow it doesn't) and opacity - to opacity to corresponding variable defined with watchOpacity attribute? This is due that I could have 100 color pickers for various parts of page, lets say, and in example above it is strictly defined what variables to use for chaned values.

Comment: Take a look at the updates I made to the Plunker and my answer. By introducing isolate scope, the directive becomes reusable. By using ng-init and the `defaultValue` attribute of the plugin config, you can initialize a default value from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly : You've defined data-opacity in your element , while you want to use it as attributes.opacity , which is not even logically correct

Secondly : in your directive , if you want to read the value of your current directive , I mean this :

```
      watch-opacity="data.opacity"
```

You need to say something like this in your directive :

```
     link:function(scope,element,attributes){
      var data_opacity = attributes.watchOpacity// you have written attribute.opacity!
```

}

I dont know what you are going to do :(

Comment: change attributes.opacity to attributes.watchOpacity , I think it will work